# How to do mean line in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´m trying to do a mean value line, but I can´t.

How can I do?

```
b%>% ggplot(aes(temp_anomaly,year)) + geom_point() +
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should post example data (a "reproducible example").

Answer (score 1):

One way would be,

```
+ geom_hline(yintercept = mean(temp_anomaly, na.rm = T))
```